# Blender 2.82 Mantaflow Bug

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation, fluid-simulation

I'm currently trying out the new fluid simulator in Blender 2.82, but I'm having a problem. I was first making some models fly around with rigid body simulations. Then I baked that simulation on each model into keyframes and I also deleted the force field that I used for that. After that I created a cube, scaled it up and applied a fluid simulation to it, categorizing it into the domain type. Then I applied a fluid simulation to each of the models and categorized them into the flow type with geometry selected. I also created a plane, which also had a fluid simulation on it and on that one I categorized it into the effector type, also remembering to check "Is planar". And after changing a few settings in the domain I baked the data and then baked the mesh (I didn't activate the particles only the mesh and the liquid). After the baking nothing happened. I tried several times fixing some stuff, for example duplicating my models, that were flow types and changed them also into effectors, changing the surface thickness of every effector to 0.0001 or just entirely freeing the data and the mesh again and then baking them again, but still no fluid is coming into my scene (even in rendered view). I hope someone can help and thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you apply the scale?

Comment: The scale of the domain?

Comment: and the other objects related to the simulation

Comment: thanks for the help, but nothing's changed now. I applied the scale on the domain and all the flows and effectors, freed the data and the mesh again and then baked them again, but still, nothing happened. Could the animation have something to do with it? I'm hoping you could maybe find a solution. Thanks in advance!